# Using Redis for application properties

Tags: spring-boot, redis

I have a web application in which we have multiple features. All these feaures can be enabled/disabled via a flag.

For ex:

```
feature.a.enabled=false
feature.b.enabled=true
```

Initially all these properties were part of application properties. Periodically (once in 2 weeks), we have an urgent requirement to turn a feature on or off. Updating property file
will rebuild the project and the pipeline will deploy the application starting from dev,qa, stg and then prod. It was so annoying. So we 
decided to move these properties to our app db. Now whenever we have the urgent requirement, we update the values in the DB, then restart all the instances of
app-servers on Prod. app-servers while starting read and cache these values. We have 50 app-servers. Rolling restarts take time.

I am thinking of suggesting using redis for this purpose. The code more or less would be like this.

```
//pseudo code
if(redisTemplate.getKeyValue("feature.a.enabled")){
    show feature
}
```

The advantage would be, I do not
have to restart the app. But I am sure it would affect the performance. Because it would be tons of network calls to redis.

Can you suggest some other alternative for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Redis was created for

> tons of network calls to Redis

but if You want to reduce the amount of those, you can use Spring Cache(In memory - because there is an option to use Redis as cache provider - once again proof that You should not worry about performance if You simply decide to approach You to mention in Your question)
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache

The flow will be:

1. You turn the feature on or off in your DB(relational or Redis)
2. Call some method that invalidates the cache(annotated with `@CacheEvict`)
3. When you call first time `redisTemplate.getKeyValue("feature.a.enabled")` result should be cached(method annotated with `@Cacheable`)
4. Any subsequent call of `redisTemplate.getKeyValue("feature.a.enabled")`(till You again do step 1. and 2.) will return the cached result

And for elegance, I will also change point 1. from manual interaction with DB to action triggered within your application.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use something else than Redis to manage your configuration. 
Take a look at [Spring Cloud Config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.2.0.RC2/reference/html/) which is done for cases like yours.

Using Redis, you have to restart your applications, with Spring Cloud Config your configurations could be refreshed, so you no longer need to restart applications.